# Using a For loop to read a value from a file - Python 3

Tags: python, list

I have the following code which doesn't quite work. The function is passed a number (say 1) which is the index number of the film. I want the program to display the ROW, for the respective index number (read from the file).

```
def viewfilmfunction(x):
  #Open the file as filmsfile
  with open("films.txt", "r") as filmsfile:
   #call upon the reader that will allow us to work with the file
     filmsfileReader=csv.reader(filmsfile)
     #for each row that is read by the reader
     for row in filmsfileReader:
        #and for each field in that row (this is done automatically)
       for field in row:
           #if the field[x] is equal to the number passed into the sub

        if field==x:
              #print the first two fields in that row which correspond to the number

              print("you have viewed film:",  x, "which is", row)
```

The text file contents are as follows:

```
0,Genre, Title, Rating, Viewed, Liked
1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, No, No
2,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, No, No
3,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, No, No
4,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, No, No
5,Drama, The English Patient, 15, No, No
6,Drama, Benhur, PG, No, No
7,Drama, The Pursuit of Happiness, 12, No, No
8,Drama, The Thin Red Line, 18, No, No
9,Romance, When Harry met Sally, 12, No, No
10,Romance, You've got mail, 12, No, No
11,Romance, Last Tango in Paris, 18, No, No
12,Romance, Casablanca, 12, No,No
```

Currently the output is:
        0
G

1
S
O

2
S
O

3
S
O

4
S
O

5
D

6
D

7
D

8
D

9
R

1
R

1
R

1
R

N

I would like the output to be as below, outputting only the second and third fields in the respective row (the genre and title):

```
"You have viewed film: 1 which is SCI-FI, Out of the Silent Planet"
```

Comment: the output is not consistent with the above code...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You have to check `if row[0] == x`

Answer (score 0):

Start using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("films.txt")
df.loc[n,]
```

Gives the desired result. This is all the code not an extract.

Comment: Thank you @e4c5. Are you able to explain each line. What does df.loc[n,] do?

Comment: The first line I think you know well, the second one reads in the entire CSV file into what's known as a pandas dataframe. This is a very versatile tool (but has quite a steep learning curve). There are lot's of different ways to get  a row from a dataframe. This is just one of them. More here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: other than getting rows by index you can do searching on them too. Even SQL like queries